# How to open div and making message readible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have created a collapsible div with reactjs which makes my content not readible. This is part of the component:

```
<div>
       {/*start collapse*/}
            <div className={"collapse" + (this.state.open ? ' in' : '')}>
            <div className="col-md-12 message"> Hello I am open nice to read this properly !!!<hr/> </div>
            </div
       {/*end collapse*/}
</div>
<div className="col-md-12 more">This should be in same position and not pushed downwards but not visible/ blurred when I click on open</div>
</div>
```

The css looks like this:

```
.message {
      position: relative;
}

div.more {
      position: absolute;
      top: 40px;
      z-index: -1;
}

div.hier {
      position: absolute;
      top: 60px;
      z-index: -1;
}
```

In the index.html I have the same issue:

```
<div id="app"></div>
  <div>
    <div class="col-md-12 hier">This should be in same position and not pushed downwards but not visible/ blurred when I click on open</div>
  </div>
```

Which css do I use to make the divs invisible/blurred and not pushed down when I click open?

Codepen [here](http://codepen.io/gekkerkanniet/pen/NbeVzj?editors=1111)

Comment: Did you make any changes? Nothing is pushed when I click "open".

Comment: Sorry I changed the question not the code, the open message still is not readible though

Comment: Maybe add a background to it so that the text underneath will be covered - see fork: http://codepen.io/azizn/pen/oYJrgg?editors=1111

Comment: how can I keep it plain ie without the background?

Comment: make it blurred or something

Comment: blurring with CSS is experimental and a bit laggy. You could maybe use a white background with opacity like: `background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a class with the property `visibility` set to `hidden`.

Applying this to an HTML element will make the tag invisible but keep it's allocated space on the page intact.